# Polymer 2.x : How do I scope Foreign stylesheets and / or Are @imports shimmed

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

There have been questions doing the rounds , making a lot of people try stubbornly force scoping an external css into a Polymer element..
by hook or crook

And then the heart break of an `@import` not working, or a `link rel=stylsheet` not scoped
So,

#### How do I as an author / consumer of a polymer element, **scope** foreign stylesheets?

#### What are some `gotchas`? is `@import` supported and shimmed?

Answer (score 0):

## Can I Scope external CSS Stylesheets to within a Polymer Custom Element

> TL;DR :
>   use `link rel=import` and pass the url of your external stylesheet to the [poly-style](https://poly-style.appspot.com/demo/) tool
>
> **Note** Polymer still can not shim an `@import` , or stuff with external urls , that require a fetch before the shim
>   Also, `<link rel=stylesheet...` is **not** scoped , but can be used.It is also, not shimmed into your element.

Polymer up until 1.0 defined the use of `<link>` tags with attributes

- `rel` = `import`
- `type` = `css`

and whatever `href` as long as it obeyed `CORS` principles

Everything was all fancy and we all held hands and sang kumbaya

With Polymer 2.0 and actually even the later versions of polymer 1.0,

something called `style-modules` were introduced where, you encapsulate

all your handwritten styles inside of a template in a `dom-module` container

```
    <dom-module id="my-style">
        <template>
            <style>
                .class_1{
                  /*all class_1 styles*/
                }
                .class_2{
                  /*all class_1 styles*/
                }
                .class_3{
                  /*all class_1 styles*/
                }
            </style>
        </template>
    </dom-module>
```

And then you'd essentially import these handwritten styles into your custom element

```
    <link rel=import href=my-style.html />
    <dom-module id="my-app">
        <template>
            <style include=my-style>
            </style>
        </template>
    </dom-module>
```

Oh Snap! Now, I'd have to copy over entire stylesheets first, then wrap them in a `<dom-module>`
and then import them over to my app! we retorted.

And then there were numerous queries about deduplication and all those sort of anxieties

So, the preferred or suggested solution rather, was to read and search through stylesheets and copy over only those classes deemed necessary.

Polymer Also **has yet** to rid itself with the **deprecated**
`<link rel=import type=css... />`
css shimmer .

basically, even with polymer 2.0, you can use the above, albeit, you now need to actually place it inside of your `<dom-module>`.

and polymer shims it.

#### Some gotchas :

- you simply can not have the dreadful `@import` rules inside those stylesheets
- `@imports` require polymer to fetch the resource `async` and hence can not guarantee a shim - **hence** no support.
- Now on some browsers, you might see this lingering in the shadows of your dev console:
  `Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type text/css: "https://a.b.com/additional.css".`
  This doesn't necessarily mean the resource wasn't fetched, but hey if your web server has a `no-sniff`
  or any content integrity header set, that'd mean, the browser can not interpret a `css` as an `html`.
  now since `<link rel=import...` is meant for `HTML Imports` , that'd mean, the browser has to accept only `html` as a response content type.

Hence, `style modules` are the best way to go while importing and scoping css to your components.

How then would I import an external stylesheet.. say a `font-awesome` ?

well, polymer has the web tool residing at

[this web based style module builder for polymer](https://poly-style.appspot.com/demo/)

Now this web tool , **duly** gives you the required `content-type` and `access-control` headers.
Since the response is `text/html` , no more warnings on the console either.

#### So, How do I build my style module?

simple, use `link rel=import` and pass the url of your external stylesheet to the poly-style tool

```
<link rel="import" href="https://poly-style.appspot.com?id=poly-fa-style-module&url=https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v4.7.0/css/font-awesome-css.min.css">
<dom-module id="poly-fa">
  <template id="poly-fa-styler" strip-whitespace>
```

Now, all you need to do is, do an `<style include=poly-fa>` within your apps. and you have a `scoped` font awesome.

**Caution!**
This will **still** not support `@import`s
Also, `::slotted` DOM, can not be styled by style-modules via shared styles, except under some scenarios where, you import the stylesheet into a higher element in the hierarchy

**Gulp**

The above tool is ideal for authors, who may choose not to prefill required external styles for their components in their custom elements, and fetch external css when necessary

for people who might want to pre fill external styles into their components, I have heard of a `gulp` plugin [here](https://github.com/MaKleSoft/gulp-style-modules) , although I am yet to use it.